# SSRS evaluate column in fill expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have a table in `SSRS`,  Grouped on customer number.
I need to evaluate the same column within the fill expressions.

The evaluation should be -
where if the `ABTAX` for the two different customers is the same and the `AIMAXO` are also the same then fill red, else leave column white.

I've tried the below expression but it just fills the whole column red.

```
=iif(Fields!ABTAX.Value = Fields!ABTAX.Value and (Fields!AIMAXO.Value = Fields!AIMAXO.Value), "RED","WHITE")
```

The Data:

```
CustomerNo     ABTAX                AIMAXO
--------------------------------------------
999991       00592235 COF           235000
999992       00592235 COF           235000
```

Comment: You are currently only checking the two values against themselves, not against any other data (effectively `if (1=1 and 2=2)`).  Can you share your dataset and report layout with us?

Comment: Are you able to edit the underlying SQL?  This would be much easier to calculate in SQL than in SSRS

Comment: yea i can edit the sql, should i create a flag essentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can alter the underlying SQL I would create a flag to show the duplicate.  A query like this would raise the correct flags*

```
SELECT 
    A.CustomerNo, 
    ABTAX, 
    AIMAXO, 
    CASE WHEN B.CustomerNo = A.CustomerNo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Duplicate
FROM @Temp A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerNo FROM @Temp
    WHERE ABTAX = (
        SELECT ABTAX
        FROM @Temp
        GROUP BY ABTAX,AIMAXO
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND AIMAXO =(
        SELECT AIMAXO
        FROM @Temp
        GROUP BY ABTAX,AIMAXO
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ON A.CustomerNo = B.CustomerNo
```

Using this source dataset

```
CustomerNo  ABTAX         AIMAXO
999991      00592235 COF  235000
999992      00592235 COF  235000
999993      00592236 COF  235000
999994      00592235 COF  235001
```

Will return the following dataset with flags

```
CustomerNo  ABTAX         AIMAXO  Duplicate
999991      00592235 COF  235000  1
999992      00592235 COF  235000  1
999993      00592236 COF  235000  0
999994      00592235 COF  235001  0
```

You can then use this duplicate flag to colour the cells appropraitely

*(*I'm willing to admit there may be a more efficient way of coding it)*